# IIS and IIS express memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ado.net, sqlconnection

I have and asp.net mvc 3 web site. When running it on local VS web server or IIS express it`s ok. But when running it on IIS (IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 R2) it seems like memory leak as memory usage is growing all the time. Any ideas?

One more update: there`s such a code in the app:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection { //creating connection here };
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

try
{
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       //read the data
    }
}
finally
{
   conn.Close();
}
```

Maybe there should be something like reader.Dispose? Can it be the cause of memory leak?

---

UPDATE: for some reason gc.Collect fixes the issue. But it`s not hte way out as calling gc.collect all the way is a bad idea.

Comment: Did your profile application? I have to say that with the information you provided about your application in this question the best we could do to help you finding the issue is wish you good luck. But when you asked this question I think it's not what you expected. So you will have to provide much more information about what your application is doing, when you are observing those memory peaks, what is the application doing at this moment, ...?

Comment: You are right, Darin. I don`t know what should I provide. It seems like if I know where it goes - I would fix it. I don`t understand how memory leak can happen on .net. We only use entity framework for DB, ninject as DI and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well best practice here would be to use brackets, this is a great feature of c#. when you use the "using" keyword with a bracket, it would dispose the used object automatically, when running out of the bracket scope. here's an example;

```
// SqlConnection implements IDisposable, will be disposed after bracket is closed
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
      conn.Open();
      // SqlCommand implements IDisposable, will be disposed after bracket is closed
      using(SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
         // DataReader implements IDisposable, will be disposed after bracket is closed
         using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
              // read here.
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Here's also the microsoft link that says "The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I hope it helps.

Comment: All (3) components should be disposed of (they all support `IDisposable`) which will automatically call `Close()` for you (in the case of `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, detay. Actually already did the changes. Will deploy now and let you know if that was the issue.

Comment: Yaroslav; If you have Analyze option on your Visual Studio, try running a code analysis on your project as well. It will tell you to use "using" with all the disposable objects in your project, among other things. Some of the warnings are mostly cosmetic and can be ignored but it would definitely increase your project's code quality overall.